# Mac mini can not login

Tags: macos, keyboard

I know this question may asked by many users but all the others answers is not helpfull, not working for me.

I started the Mac mini,
Logone screen appears,
I tried to type the password 3 to 4 times, but unable to login.

Then I use Mac keyboard with otg cable and connect my android phone.
I tried to type the password and most of the key is not working, few working.

Say when I press 'a' works,
Press 'd' not works, nothing display,
Press space , display 'm' and so on.
What can be the issue?

How can I login to Mac if keyboard not working.

Have not enabled the ssh or remot access?

Does regular usb keyboard will work if I purchase a new keyboard? Or have to purchase new Mac keyboard for my Mac mini?

Better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I replace a new windows based keyboard and works as needed.